# (111 Connection Refused) Can't connect db using python

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I'm trying to connect my DB using the script below, but a get this error..

> Error: '2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111
> Connection refused)

I can access normally with phpMyAdmin (on localhost, using default port 3306)

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def conect_test(host_name, user_name, user_password):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password,
            use_pure=True
        )
        print("MySQL Database connection successful")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Erro: '{err}'")

    return connection
```

I can manage the DB properly using PhpMyAdmin, no errors, and everything is local.

Comment: The connection refused makes clear there is nothing listening on port 3306 on localhost, or that a firewall doesn't allow you to connect.

Comment: There is nothing listen on port 3306... i tried 
...
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
...
then
..
sudo netstat -atn 

then I got

127.0.0.1:1431          0.0.0.0:*               listen
0 0.0.0.0:1433            0.0.0.0:*               listen
127.0.0.1:40063         0.0.0.0:*               listen

Comment: Then you don't have a MySQL server running on localhost (or at least not on port 3306). Is your PHPMyAdmin maybe on a remote host (so its localhost is not your machine)?